# How exactly does a XOR Linked list work?

Tags: algorithm

The following  [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/xor-linked-list-a-memory-efficient-doubly-linked-list-set-1/)  explains it.
 The implementation  is said to work by storing the XOR of the previous and next address(say nxp), instead of storing both(previous and next address) separately.However, further along the implementation is said to work by **xor-ing** the previous address and nxp, in order to get the *next address*.

But isnt this practically using the  **same space** as having previous and next pointers?

Comment: Compare the normal implementation of 2 pointers per node and 1 pointer per node for XOR linked list and you will see the difference. (Note that this is doubly linked list)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In a doubly linked list, you store two pointers per node: prev and next. In an XOR linked list, you store one 'pointer' per node, which is the XOR of prev and next (or if one of them is absent, just the other (the same as XORing with 0)). The reason why you can still traverse an XOR linked list in both directions relies on the properties of XOR and the redundancy of information inherent in a double linked list.

---

Imagine you have three nodes in your XOR linked list.

A is the head, and has an unobfuscated pointer to B (B XOR 0, next only)

B is the middle element, and has the XOR of pointers to A and to C.

C is the tail, and an unobfuscated pointer to B (0 XOR B, prev only)

When I am iterating over this list, I start at A. I note A's position in memory as I travel to B. When I wish to travel to C, I XOR B's pointer with A, granting me the pointer to C. I then note B's position in memory and travel to C.

This works because XOR has the property of undoing itself if applied twice: C XOR A XOR A == C. Another way to think about it is, the doubly linked list stores no extra information a singly linked list does not (since it's just storing all the previous pointers as copies of next pointers somewhere else in memory), so by exploiting this redundancy we can have doubly linked list properties with only as many links as are needed. **However,** This only works if we start our XOR linked list traversal from the start or end — as if we just jump into a random node in the middle, we do not have the information necessary to start traversing.

---

While an XOR linked list has the advantage of smaller memory usage, it has disadvantages — it will confuse the compiler, debugging and static analysis tools as your XOR of two pointers will not be correctly recognized by a pointer by anything except your code. It also slows down pointer access to have to do the XOR operation to recover the true pointer first. It also can't be used in managed code — XOR obfuscated pointers won't be recognized by the garbage collector.

Comment: @nhahtdh I am answering the question 'But isnt this practically using the same space as having previous and next pointers?' by explaining how an XOR linked list fits both previous and next pointers in the same space in memory. What have I missed? :)

Comment: @nhahtdh I explain that you can traverse an XOR linked list in both directions yet with the same amount of memory storage as a singly linked list by exploiting the redundancy of information inherent in a doubly linked list. How is that not answering the question?

Comment: I think you can improve your answer by adding the point `an XOR linked list fits both previous and next pointers in the same space in memory.` in your answer. Currently, I can't see relation between your answer and the question.

Comment: I think you're missing the point; the OP probably doesn't misunderstand XOR (or at least might have the same question anyway).  The OP probably is missing the fact that DLL stores p/n for each node, while XLL stores x(p/n) for each node and last_traversed one time rather than for each node.

Answer (score 8):

Let us consider the following XOR list

A->B->C->D

suppose you created nodes in this format below

Key|Link|

```
A|0^addr(B)| ->  B|addr(A)^addr(C)|  ->  C|addr(B)^addr(D)| -> D|addr(C)^0|
```

***CASE #1:[Forward Traversal]*** Now Suppose you are in B (current_node=>B) want visit C , so you need Address of C . How you will get ?

> **Addressof(Next_node) = addressof(Prev_node) ^ Current_node(Link)**

```
addr(A)^ ( addr(A)^ addr(C) )
=>(addr(A) ^ addr(A)) ^ addr(C) 
=> 0 ^ addr(C)
=>addr(C)
```

***CASE #2: [Backward traversal]*** Now Suppose you are in C (current_node=> C) want visit B , so you need Address of B . How you will get ?

> **Addressof(Prev_node) = addressof(Next_node) ^ Current_node(Link)**

```
addr(D) ^ ((addr(B) ^ addr(D)) 
=> (addr(D)^ addr(D)) ^ addr(B)
=> 0^addr(B)
=> addr(B)
```

**Traversing:**
*To traverse whole list ,You will need 3 pointers  **prevPtr , currPtr , nextPtr** to store relative current, previous and next node's address starting with head.
Then in each iteration these pointers need be move to one position ahead.*

```
struct Node *currPtr = head;
struct Node *prevPtr = NULL;
struct Node *nextPtr;

printf ("Following are the nodes of Linked List: \n");

while (currPtr != NULL)
{
    // print current node
    printf ("%d ", currPtr->key);

    // Save the address of next node
    nextPtr = XOR (prevPtr, currPtr->link);

    //move prevPtr and currPtr one position for next iteration

    prevPtr = currPtr;
    currPtr = nextPtr;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> But isnt this practically using the same space as having previous and
>   next pointers?

No - it uses about half the space, as the size of the result of XOR-ing the "prev" and "next" is equal to the size of the larger of the two.

Answer (score 5):

XOR has a very special property about it, namely, given `a XOR b = c`, only two (any two) of the variable are required to compute the the third, *with some restrictions*. See the [XOR swap algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) for why this works.

In this case the previous (or next) pointer *must still be carried*, but only through traversal calculations and not as a seperate member.

Comment: It would be nice if you quoted a relevant excerpt from your link.

Answer (score 4):

Double linked list needs 2*N pointers stored for N nodes, plus at least one additional pointer(head, or perhaps head and tail).

XOR linked list needs N pointers stored for N nodes, plus at least two additional pointers (head and last visited node, or perhaps head and tail and last visited node).  While traversing, you store one node (the last visited node), but when you go to the next node, you rewrite that with the now-previous node's address.

Comment: Actually, you need N+2 pointers for N nodes. To traverse in either direction, you need one un-XORed pointer to the first node, and another to the last node.

Comment: Disagree (at least, for the general case).  If you want to be able to traverse from both directions at once (independently), sure, you'd need that; but if you just want the ability to go backwards or forwards form the current node, you just need a single pointer to the last node traversed.  You can then go back to that pointer, or fowards to the XOR of that pointer and the one on the list.  Not all DLLs (or even most) are created to allow traversal from both ends.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: A doubly linked list needs those as well, so you might as well focus on just the pointers in the actual nodes, in which case it's `2*N` vs `N`.

Comment: Edited to make the above a bit clearer.  I suppose even that's inaccurate as if you do not need to remember the head or tail pointer, it is still N+1, but that's more confusing than needed here I think.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
link = previous ^ next
```

therefore:

```
previous = link ^ next
next = link ^ previous
```

in order to obtain `previous`, you need to xor `link` with `next`, to obtain `next`, you need to xor `link` with `previous`. You can look at `link` as a pointer that can yield both `next` and `previous`, but not without a minor performance cost.

It is sometimes useful to think of `next` as a child node and `previous` as a parent node.